# Creating a CloudWatch Scheduled Event with arbitrary data in the `detail` field

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lambda, go

I'd like to run a Lambda task on a fixed schedule, with some configuration passed into it by the CloudWatch Scheduled Event that triggers the task. Looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#schedule_event_type), I can see that Cloudwatch Scheduled Events look like this:

```
{
  "id": "53dc4d37-cffa-4f76-80c9-8b7d4a4d2eaa",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2015-10-08T16:53:06Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [ "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:rule/MyScheduledRule" ],
  "detail": {}
}
```

My Lambda task is written in Go, and I can see that `event.CloudWatchEvent` lets me access the JSON in the event's `detail` field, but I can't figure out how to create a Cloudwatch Scheduled Event rule with some custom detail. Any thoughts?

Comment: you may want to move this questions to just `stackoverflow` from `serverfault` for good visibility by AWS team

Answer (score 3):

```
# This is for AWS Sam CF
MyScheduledRule:
    Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
    Properties:
      Description: "ScheduledRule"
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(6 minutes)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Arn:
            !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
          Id: "IdForAlert" 
          Input: "{\"name\": \"value\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect answer, but I wound up communicating to the Lambda task using env vars.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html